# Unable to dynamically add a function to submit button on a form in the WordPress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick, frontend

The landing page in our WordPress site has a form where I try to add `onclick="if(validate()){ doYourPostRequest(); }"` with the unsuccessful code below.

```
$form('.ff-btn ff-btn-submit').attr('onClick', 'if(validate()){ doYourPostRequest(); }');
```

Please note `$form: The Javascript (jQuery) DOM object of the Form`

Below is where I expect to see `onClick` attribute like `onClick=if(validate()){ doYourPostRequest(); }')` It does add nothing leaving me wondering why.

```
<button type="submit" class="ff-btn ff-btn-submit   ff-btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery docs for the `.attr()` method:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled > state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Better yet, since you are creating an event handler, you should consider changing your syntax altogether to use the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) method.

Assuming `$form` is as you state, something like this:

```
$form('.ff-btn ff-btn-submit').on('click', ()=> { 
  if(validate()) { 
     doYourPostRequest(); 
  }
});
```

or

```
$form.on('submit', handler);
```

or the short cut:

```
$form.submit(handler);
```

Comment: Hi Randy, could you please kindly look at my post here on how to get elements by class name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830436/iterate-through-textarea-fields-under-a-specific-element-and-strip-emojis-from-t. Please suggest some possible solutions.